# How to create a Normal Distribution Normal Distribution in D3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js, jqplot, protovis

I want to create a  Normal Distribution Chart (Bell Curve) in d3.js.

like this [http://statwiki.ucdavis.edu/@api/deki/files/73/a9f781e1b0891ceedd50cd7fea7d0f39.jpg?revision=1][1]

I have tried search in google but I am not able to get any example of the same. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you really need to do is prepare a line chart and compute the pdf.  D3 provides the charting framework and Jason Davies Science library the stats.

The d3 line function boils down to:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.q);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.p);
    });
```

And your Bell curve coordinates can be calculated using the Box-Muller Transform and passing this to the Gaussian pdf.

You can see this all put together in this [Bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/88cb8a51cdce45f13c7e).  You should also check out the links in the code.